# Full-height header not working

Tags: css, header

I was trying to make a header fill the screen using this CSS:

```
position:relative; 
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-height:100%; 
background-image:{image:topbar};
z-index:1;
```

But when scrolling, there's more of the image to be shown and I have no idea what's wrong, please help?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add `background-repeat:no-repeat;`